# HTTP2のHPACKにおける"インデックスされないリテラルヘッダフィールド"について

Tags: http, ssl, http2, hpack

http://syucream.github.io/hpack-spec-ja/header-compression-10-ja.html

6.2.3 インデックスされないリテラルヘッダフィールド

の箇所に

> インデックスされないリテラルヘッダフィールド表現は 動的テーブルの変更を伴わずにデコードされたヘッダリストへの
>   ヘッダフィールドの追加を引き起こします。 中継者はこのヘッダフィールドのエンコードに同じ表現を 使用しなければなりません (MUST) 。

とあります。
これは「6.2.2 インデックス更新を伴わないリテラルヘッダフィールド」と何が違うのでしょうか？

> この表現は圧縮によるリスクに晒されないよう ヘッダフィールド値を保護することを意図しています (詳細は Section 7.1 を 参照)
>   。

と書かれています。
私はCRIME攻撃に詳しくないですが、MSBに「0001」を使用する以外はフォーマットは同じように見えます。
なぜこれでヘッダフィールド値を保護できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

§7.1.3に書かれていますが、これはセキュリティ上の理由からわざと冗長なエンコードで送信したヘッダを、プロキシサーバー側で勝手に最適化されないように通知するためのものです。

ですからプロキシサーバー側がこのヘッダーを正しく扱っていないと効果がありません。

> 7.1.3 インデックスされないリテラル
>
> ヘッダフィールドのインデックス表現の生成を止める ことは圧縮がすべてのホップで行われない場合のみ 影響します。インデックスされないリテラル(Section 6.2.3 を 参照) は中継者に特定の値が意図的にリテラルとして 送信されたことを通知するのに使用できます。中継者はインデックスを伴うインデックスされないリテラルを 使用する値を再エンコードしてはいけません (MUST NOT) 。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解しました。